# why window.setTimeout is required to set an iframe's designmode "on" in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, designmode

In my experiment, I have seen that even after window.onload event, window.setTimeout is required to make an iframe editable by setting iframe's designmode "ON". And this happens in IE, while in Firefox window.setTimeout is not required. I have not tested in any other browser.

Is it necessary to use window.setTimeout to set an iframe's designmode "ON" in IE?

You can try it from here, http://www.nazmulweb.com/site5/demo/iframe/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off setting the `contentEditable` property of the iframe's `<body>` to `true` instead, which I think will work immediately. I've done that in WYSIWYG editors I've written, although now I can't remember why. I'm pretty sure I had decent reasons.

Comment: That is an alternative solution to make WYSIWYG. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `designmode='on'` when iframe is loaded.